# Baking Constraint

Tags: animation, export, baking, constraints, unreal-engine

I have obtained a baked animation project, but I would like to add more animations to it. May I cancel the baking for this project? Do I only need to clear all keyframes after the first frame to undo baking? Is this idea correct? I am not very familiar with baking knowledge.
I cleaned up all keyframes except for the first frame according to my own ideas and reset the correct constraints. However, when I baked and exported to UE again, the animation only applied the constraints of the first frame, and all frames after the first frame did not apply the constraints I had set,
How can I make every frame of the re baked animation constrained?

Comment: This really depends on the details of the constraints used and the keyframed values.